# Is there a procedure to initialize a variable number of objects at runtime in single procedure?

Tags: freepascal, delphi

I usually have initialize some variables like the TStringList type at the start of procedures and free them afterwards.It feels awkward to initialize the separately, like

```
listOne := TStringList.Create;
listTwo := TStringList.Create;
listTree := TString.Create;
{ etc, etc}
```

I would prefer a procedure like, with another for Free ing them a the end:

```
CreateStrings(listOne, listTwo, listThree);
CreateStrings([listOne, listTwo, listTree]); //using an array
```

Is there a procedure that can do something like this for a variable number of objects?

If it can't be done for arbitrary object types, at least for similar types or types with the same Create signature?

Comment: You could wrap the lists in a single class if a) you do this often and b) they tend to be used together in the code

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is this:

```
PROCEDURE CreateObjects(ClassType : TClass ; VAR O1); OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    TObject(O1):=NIL;
    TObject(O1):=ClassType.Create
  END;

PROCEDURE CreateObjects(ClassType : TClass ; VAR O1,O2); OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    TObject(O1):=NIL; TObject(O2):=NIL;
    TObject(O1):=ClassType.Create; TObject(O2):=ClassType.Create
  END;

PROCEDURE CreateObjects(ClassType : TClass ; VAR O1,O2,O3); OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    TObject(O1):=NIL; TObject(O2):=NIL; TObject(O3):=NIL;
    TObject(O1):=ClassType.Create; TObject(O2):=ClassType.Create; TObject(O3):=ClassType.Create
  END;

PROCEDURE FreeObjects(CONST Objects : ARRAY OF TObject);
  VAR
    O   : TObject;
    E   : Exception;
    ADR : POINTER;

  BEGIN
    E:=NIL;
    FOR O IN Objects DO TRY
      O.Free
    EXCEPT
      ON X:Exception DO BEGIN
        E:=X; ADR:=ExceptAddr
      END
    END;
    IF Assigned(E) THEN RAISE E AT ADR
  END;

PROCEDURE TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender : TObject);
  VAR
    SL1,SL2 : TStrings;

  BEGIN
    CreateObjects(TStringList,SL1,SL2);
    FreeObjects([SL1,SL2])
  END;
```

You'll need to make an overloaded procedure for each count of objects you want to create simultaneously. All objects in the same CreateObjects call will be created as the same type (which you'll give as the first parameter), and can only be created using that type's parameterless constructor.

The reason for the NIL assignment before construction is to make sure that the passed-in variables always have a valid value (either NIL or pointing to a class of the requested type). This also means that in contrast to a normal code:

```
O:=TObject.Create;
TRY
  // Blah, Blah
FINALLY
  O.Free
END;
```

you should use

```
TRY
  CreateObjects(TObject,O1,O2);
  // Blah, Blah
FINALLY
  FreeObjects([O1,O2])
END;
```

ie. move the creation of the objects within the TRY/FINALLY block.

If you are a supporter of FreeAndNIL, then you can make this:

```
PROCEDURE FreeAndNilObjects(VAR O1,O2); OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    TRY
      FreeAndNIL(O1)
    FINALLY
      FreeAndNIL(O2)
    END
  END;

PROCEDURE FreeAndNilObjects(VAR O1,O2,O3); OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    TRY
      FreeAndNIL(O1)
    FINALLY
      TRY
        FreeAndNIL(O2)
      FINALLY
        FreeAndNIL(O3)
      END
    END
  END;
```

This a bit odd construct makes sure that FreeAndNIL is called on all passed-in objects, but also means that if any exception occurs, it'll be the LAST exception raised that you'll receive, and any previous exceptions will be lost. It does make sure, however, that all objects are (attempted) free'd.

EDIT: Updated FreeObjects to properly handle any exceptions that might occur in the .Free call of any of the objects. Like the FreeAndNilObjects procedures, it'll eat any exception except the last one, and re-raise this after having ensured that .Free is at least attempted called on every passed-in object.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure CreateObjects(Vars: array of Pointer; ClassType: TClass);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(Vars) to High(Vars) do
    TObject(Vars[I]^) := ClassType.Create;
end;

procedure FreeObjects(Vars: array of TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(Vars) to High(Vars) do
    Vars[I].Free;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  TestString = 'A,B,C,"4th line","line 5","last line"';
var
  StringList1: TStringList;
  StringList2: TStringList;
  StringList3: TStringList;
begin
  CreateObjects([@StringList1, @StringList2, @StringList3], TStringList);
  try
    StringList1.CommaText := TestString;
    StringList2.CommaText := TestString;
    StringList3.CommaText := TestString;
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(StringList1);
    ListBox1.Items.Assign(StringList2);
    RichEdit1.Lines.Assign(StringList3);
  finally
    FreeObjects([StringList1, StringList2, StringList3]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What if StringList1 gets successfully created, but an exception is raised during the creation of StringList2 ?

Comment: @HeartWare Yeah. Since all objects are of the same kind, that exception would be EOutOfMemory I imagine; then it'll be the least of your problems. But thanks for the warning; strictly speaking this code could leak objects.

Comment: Not necessarily (EOutOfMemory). What if the class type is "TMyOwnClassTypeThatFailsOnEvery2ndCall" (ie. one, where the constructor may fail for any other reason than EOutOfMemory, but for a very "natural" reason?). F.ex. a constructor that empties a Queue and transfers information to its internal variables and then the queu runs dry?